# IntelliJ community edition 2018.2 Unable to import maven project: See logs for details

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ on Mac OS Mojave and having an issue loading maven projects in the IDE

- I updated my IntelliJ to latest version i.e. 2018.2 community edition
- Updated my JDK to 11.0.1
- updated maven to 3.5.4

Now I am not able to see maven projects in my IDE and my IDE keeps on showing me "Unable to import" error in the events logs window. Strangely I can compile the project using mvn commands from terminal but cant see the maven projects in IDE window.

[error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe80p.png)

I also tried to check the logs which has following in it. I have made sure that Java version used by IntelliJ is version 11. I also tried clearing the idea folder as suggested for other similar questions but that did not help either

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaakg.png)

```
    018-10-31 00:45:28,583 [ 119986]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Activity run in 109ms on UI thread 
2018-10-31 00:45:29,001 [ 120404]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 233 ms spent on EDT to cache options in project 
2018-10-31 00:45:29,585 [ 120988]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Unrecognized option: -d64 
2018-10-31 00:45:29,585 [ 120988]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. 
2018-10-31 00:45:29,585 [ 120988]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. 
2018-10-31 00:45:29,630 [ 121033]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Unrecognized option: -d64 
2018-10-31 00:45:29,630 [ 121033]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. 
2018-10-31 00:45:29,630 [ 121033]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. 
2018-10-31 00:45:29,632 [ 121035]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Cannot reconnect. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.applyProfiles(MavenServerManager.java:526)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.applyProfiles(MavenProjectReader.java:394)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.doReadProjectModel(MavenProjectReader.java:103)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.readProject(MavenProjectReader.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProject.read(MavenProject.java:655)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.doUpdate(MavenProjectsTree.java:555)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.doAdd(MavenProjectsTree.java:500)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.update(MavenProjectsTree.java:461)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.updateAll(MavenProjectsTree.java:432)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessorReadingTask.perform(MavenProjectsProcessorReadingTask.java:60)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.doProcessPendingTasks(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:132)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.access$000(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:32)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor$2.run(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:107)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil.lambda$runInBackground$5(MavenUtil.java:449)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start maven service; nested exception is: 
    com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Unrecognized option: -d64
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:161)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:66)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.lambda$applyProfiles$3(MavenServerManager.java:526)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Unrecognized option: -d64
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:159)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:158)
    ... 24 more
2018-10-31 00:45:29,633 [ 121036]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.5  Build #IC-182.4892.20 
2018-10-31 00:45:29,633 [ 121036]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release 
2018-10-31 00:45:29,633 [ 121036]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2018-10-31 00:45:29,633 [ 121036]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2018-10-31 00:45:29,633 [ 121036]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - OS: Mac OS X 
2018-10-31 00:45:29,633 [ 121036]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Last Action: EditorBackSpace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I managed to solve it by uninstalling IntelliJ, deleting all the setting from current and previous versions of IntelliJ ( ⁨Users⁩/⁨/⁨Library⁩/ ⁨Preferences⁩) and then reinstalling it again

Before that , I tried all the following as suggested in various posts that did not help much in my case

- Cleaning up .idea folder
- setting up PATH variables correctly
- Using maven from installed directory instead of bundled option

Most important part was cleaning up the old settings and a simple reinstall did not work for me.

What I am not sure still is that what was causing "Invalid options -d64" error from those settings. But finally now I can try out latest Java, Maven and IntelliJ

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue with JDK 10/11: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-195143. Bug is fixed in 2018.3

Comment: Thanks. Good to know

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are running Maven with an unrecognized option, `-d64`, and that's causing that error. Check your Maven settings in IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks Alexis. I checked those and did not find this option in maven settings